# Get tuples with max value from each key from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

`[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (6, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3)]`

I want to keep the tuples which have the max first value of every tuple with the same second value. For example `(2, 1)` and `(3, 1)` share the same second (key) value, so I just want to keep the one with the max first value -> `(3, 1)`. In the end I would get this:

`[(1, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3)]`

I don't mind at all if it is not a one-liner but I was wondering about an efficient way to go about this...

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking... The max of what?

Comment: I tried to make it clear but I am not sure I was successful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

[max(items) for key, items in groupby(L,key = itemgetter(1))]
```

It's assuming that you initial list of tuples is sorted by key values.

`groupby` creates an iterator that yields objects like `(0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x01321330>)`, where the first value is the key value, the second one is another iterator which gives all the tuples with that key.

`max(items)` just selects the tuple with the maximum value, and since all the second values of the group are the same (and is also the key), it gives the tuple with the maximum first value.

A list comprehension is used to form an output list of tuples based on the output of these functions.

Comment: If its not you could make it so: `L.sort(key=itemgetter(1))`.  Of course, we don't know if the OP wants stability...

Comment: @Zach Yeah, I was contemplating sorting. But I'm not sure if it's more effective that using dictionary like in the answer if KQ. Since don't need the whole initial list in the sorted order, we just need only some of the tuples.

Comment: And sorting may take more rearrangements of the items of the initial list that just passing once trough them to form a dictionary.

Comment: Since my tuples were already naturally sorted, I used this code. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: More "code-dump style" answers should be updated with explanations like this, nice!

Comment: @agf Thanks for corrections of my English. I definitely should be more careful with choosing words (e.g. 'filter out' was too daring of me too use and eventually appeared to be not the same as 'select').

Comment: @ovgolovin It was understandable already, but the clearer the better when someone new to Python / programming might read it, and I really like the `for key, items in` form better than the indexing in the call to `max` :) Good answer either way.

Comment: After some tests I found that this code is not completely correct: the last tuple is not taken into account. If one replace [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (6, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3)] by [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (6, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3), (2,0)] the output will be [(1, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3), (2, 0)] instead of the desired output [(1, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3)].

Comment: @Rivers `(2, 3)` and `(2, 0)` have different second value in the tuple. So they can't be compacted into single `(2, 3)`. At least it is not what the OP asked to do in the question.

Comment: @ovgolovin You should have misread my comment: the problem is not with ```(2, 3)``` and ```(2, 0)``` but with ```(1,0)``` and ```(2, 0)```. If we append ```(2, 0)``` to the list, the output will be [(1, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3), (2, 0)] instead of the desired output [(1, 0), (3, 1), (6, 2), (2, 3)].

Comment: @Rivers Got it now. It is because this solution is only for the case when the original list is sorted by tuple key. I mentioned that in the answer right after the code. For unsorted sequence see the answer by KQ.

Comment: @ovgolovin You're right! I missed this part. The list of tuples must be sorted by key before. The ```key``` is the argument passed to ```groupby```, and in this case that's each second elements of the tuples (of index 1). Thanks for your elucidation!

Answer (score 4):

Probably using a dict:

```
rd = {}
for V,K in my_tuples:
  if V > rd.setdefault(K,V):
    rd[K] = V
result = [ (V,K) for K,V in rd.items() ]
```

Comment: I think this approach is more effective if the initial list is unsorted, since it takes only one passing through the tuples of initial list, hence `O(n)` complexity. And using `groupby` iterator would require initial sorting of unsorted list, so `O(n*log(n))` complexity.

Comment: Good answer too because it works even if the list of tuples in not sorted (in this case, sorted by the second element of the tuples) as mentioned by ovgolovin.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import operator
l = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (6, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3)]
result = list(max(v, key=operator.itemgetter(0)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(l, operator.itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary keyed on the second element of the tuple:

```
l = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1), (6, 2), (3, 2), (2, 3)]
d = dict([(t[1], None) for t in l])
for v, k in l:
  if d[k] < v:
    d[k] = v 
l2 = [ (v, k) for (k, v) in d.items() if v != None ]
print l2
```

Comment: The itertools based solutions are a) likely to be faster and b) considerably more elegant.  Use one of them.