# Filtering a list of tuples by the first value and checking presence of a second item in the tuple using list comp

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
a = [(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (1260000.0, 'google'), (1008000.0, 'IBM'),
(990000.0, 'google'), (792000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB'), (600000.0, 'google'), 
(504000.0,'FB'), (480000.0, 'IBM'), (420000.0, 'google'), (400000.0, 'google'),
(396000.0, 'FB'), (336000.0, 'IBM'), (330000.0, 'google'), (320000.0, 'IBM'),
(280000.0, 'google'), (264000.0, 'IBM'), (240000.0, 'FB'), (224000.0, 'IBM'),
(220000.0, 'google'), (176000.0, 'IBM'), (168000.0, 'FB'), (160000.0, 'FB'),
(132000.0, 'FB'), (112000.0, 'FB'), (88000.0, 'FB')]
```

I want to get the following ( list comprehensions is what I am trying to achieve ):

```
[(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB')]
```

Basically, get the highest value of each unique second argument of each tuple.

What I've tried ( pseudo ):

```
[max(x) for x in a if x[1] not in this list] 
# I don't know if / how I can refer to the list comprehension list while 
# its being built
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get tuples with max value from each key from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590932/get-tuples-with-max-value-from-each-key-from-a-list)

Comment: In general, you can't refer to a list comprehension while it's being built

Comment: @RajatMishram not sure how I would use `[max(items) for key, items in groupby(L,key = itemgetter(1))]` in my case, what does `L` stand for?, Also this provides every tuple mentioned in the output. Not the unique only.

Comment: "L" is the name of the liste, so "a" in your example.

Comment: @Rivers Using `[max(items) for key, items in groupby(a,key = itemgetter(1))]` gives me the full list instead of having only 3 items unique by the second item in the tuple.

Comment: Yes you're right. I posted a comment in that post, the code provided is not not completely correct.

Comment: Indeed, the code is correct, you have to sort the list of tuples beforehand. But you can do it without sorting your list. See the answer of KQ in the post linked by Rajat: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7591019/14394522

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `set` for example

```
a = [(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (1260000.0, 'google'), (1008000.0, 'IBM'),
(990000.0, 'google'), (792000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB'), (600000.0, 'google'), 
(504000.0,'FB'), (480000.0, 'IBM'), (420000.0, 'google'), (400000.0, 'google'),
(396000.0, 'FB'), (336000.0, 'IBM'), (330000.0, 'google'), (320000.0, 'IBM'),
(280000.0, 'google'), (264000.0, 'IBM'), (240000.0, 'FB'), (224000.0, 'IBM'),
(220000.0, 'google'), (176000.0, 'IBM'), (168000.0, 'FB'), (160000.0, 'FB'),
(132000.0, 'FB'), (112000.0, 'FB'), (88000.0, 'FB')]
a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0],reverse=True)#sort by 1 tuple value
ans = []
s = set() #we save the values of names that have already been used
for i in a:
    if i[1] not in s:
        ans.append(i)
        s.add(i[1])
del s
print(ans)
```