# Filtering list of tuples using itemgetter and list comp in order to get unique items based on the second item in the tuple

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I've got a list like this:

```
a = [(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (1260000.0, 'google'), (1008000.0, 'IBM'),
(990000.0, 'google'), (792000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB'), (600000.0, 'google'), 
(504000.0,'FB'), (480000.0, 'IBM'), (420000.0, 'google'), (400000.0, 'google'),
(396000.0, 'FB'), (336000.0, 'IBM'), (330000.0, 'google'), (320000.0, 'IBM'),
(280000.0, 'google'), (264000.0, 'IBM'), (240000.0, 'FB'), (224000.0, 'IBM'),
(220000.0, 'google'), (176000.0, 'IBM'), (168000.0, 'FB'), (160000.0, 'FB'),
(132000.0, 'FB'), (112000.0, 'FB'), (88000.0, 'FB')]
```

I want to get the following using itemgetter. Its the max value of the first item in the tuple unique per the second item of the tuple:

```
[(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB')]
```

What I've tried:

```
[max(items) for key, items in groupby(a,key = itemgetter(1))]
```

But it returns the full list, although it is the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590932/get-tuples-with-max-value-from-each-key-from-a-list).

How can I achieve the desired output using `itemgetter` with a list comprehension?

Comment: you need to sort `a` by second item in tuple to correctly work with `groupby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` groups *consecutive* equal values according to some key. For it to work you'd have to sort according to the second field. But then the complexity becomes unnecessarily high for what we need.

Here, you're probably better off with a dictionary. We can set keys to `0` by default and update if we find a higher value:

```
d = {}
for v,k in a:
     if d.setdefault(k, 0) < v:
            d[k] = v

print(d)
{'google': 1800000.0, 'IBM': 1440000.0, 'FB': 720000.0}
```

To obtain the same format as above:

```
[(v,k) for k,v in d.items()]
[(1800000.0, 'google'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (720000.0, 'FB')]
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby()` only works for *adjacent* similar elements. You need to sort the list first by the same key (`sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1))`), if you want it to capture and combine *all* elements with the same key:

```
[max(items) for _, items in groupby(sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1)), key = itemgetter(1))]
# [(720000.0, 'FB'), (1440000.0, 'IBM'), (1800000.0, 'google')]
```